# Create "Simple Menu" according to Material design spec

Tags: android, material-design

According to this http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus, the first menu item aligned with the vertical center of the originating row, like this:
[image: first popup menu vertically aligns with item]

I'm trying to create this menu for a `ListView` item click like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bus_line_popup, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...);
    popup.show();
}
```

However the menu then does not appear properly and according to the spec:
[image: popup menu does not appear centered]

How can I make the menu appear exactly as required?

Comment: You may want to edit the link to: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus

Comment: No problem, i did a little bit search about it, see: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Menus-and-Popups#popup-window i think you're right, sounds like a trick to do that.

Comment: Can't you just change the Gravity parameter?

Comment: @mvai tried that, but will not have an effect.

Comment: @LinX64, checked your link as well but seems not fit perfectly. I have a feeling that PopupMenu is not ported to Material Design yet

Comment: Exactly, that's the point :)

Comment: Perhaps we wait for the next support-design library which contains the class then.

Comment: @SebastianRoth - check this out: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200122#c1 it seems to be normal like i said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little bit search, See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

> A `PopupMenu` displays a `Menu` ***in a modal popup window anchored to a
>   View***. The popup will appear **below the anchor** view **if there is room**, **or
>   above it if there is not**. If the IME is visible the popup will not
>   overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will
>   dismiss it.

As [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) says, **it seems to be normal** when there is room, it will show up below the view(***like your case***) and if there is no roow, it will show up ***above the view***.

Comment: The question might be invalid in the end. The PopupMenu shown in the Material Spec is for option selections (sort of a option menu) but the PopupMenu itself is just that.. a popup menu. Google's answer in the bug tracker is correct, as the component works. I will accept your answer as it outlines the `PopupMenu` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible:

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">12dp</item>
</style>
```

`PopupMenu pm = new PopupMenu(context, view, 0, 0, R.style.MyPopupMenu);`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which might be feasible depending on your layout:
If you can insert a zero size spacer above the tappable view which can be referenced from your current code context you can use this as your "anchor" view (the one you set in the PopupMenu constructor) to achive the inline effect described on http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus